Spring circular dependency
I have this code:
Config.java:
public class Config {
    int a;
    String b;
    float c;
    long d;
// getters and setters
}

ClassB.java (this class is supposed to read application.properties and produce a config from it):
@ConfigurationProperties
@Configuration
@Component
public class ClassB { 
    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    Config config = new Config();

    @Bean
    public Config getConfig() {
        return config;
    }

    public void setConfig(Config config) {
        this.config = config;
    }    
}

ClassA.java:
@Configuration
@Component
public class ClassA {   // consumes config
    Config config;

    public ClassA(Config config) {
        if (config == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        this.config = config;
    }
}

and application.properties:
config.a=1
config.b=foo
config.c=3.14
config.d=1234567890L

This code gives me following exception:
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

   classA defined in file [/Users/xxx/code/temp/spring-cycle/target/classes/com/example/demo/ClassA.class]
┌─────┐
|  classB
└─────┘

Why? How can I fix this? Interestingly if I modify application.properties like so:
a=1
b=foo
c=3.14
d=1234567890L

then there is no exception but of course in this case the config variable is not initialized with the values from application.properties.
can anyone help me?

Something is either an @Configuration or an @Component not both. So decide what it should be. Also ClassA has a dependency on something that isn't a bean (at least not in your code sample).

you may be able to use the
@Value("${<variable name in application.properties>}")
on the config class like so:
public class Config {
    @Value("${a}")
    int a;
    @Value("${b}")
    String b;
    @Value("${c}")
    float c;
    @Value("${d}")
    long d;
// getters and setters
}

this will auto initialize the variables from the .properties file directly and I think you may not need class A, class B.
Let me know if this works
